# Javafx - Binding data from database to choicebox using JPA - EclipseLink

Tags: database, javafx, combobox, nullpointerexception, entity

I have created an entity of a table with name **Category** and I want to get the data as an entity and display the name of the category into a **choicebox** using **StringConverter**.

The problem is when I call addAll() method, it occurs a **NullPointerException**.
Here is my code:

```
private ChoiceBox<Category> chbDisplayCustomCategory;

   @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Glory_StorePU");
        eManager = emFactory.createEntityManager();
        Query query = eManager.createNamedQuery("Category.findAll", Category.class);
        List<Category> list = query.getResultList();
        ObservableList<Category> result=FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);
        chbDisplayCustomCategory.getItems().addAll(result);
            }
```

Here is the Entity class (Automatically generated):

```
package MainPack.Entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findByCatName", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.catName = :catName")})
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "CAT_NAME")
    private String catName;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Category(Long id, String catName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.catName = catName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCatName() {
        return catName;
    }

    public void setCatName(String catName) {
        this.catName = catName;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Category)) {
            return false;
        }
        Category other = (Category) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MainPack.Entities.Category[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

so can you help me please ?

Comment: Post the FXML file. Did you annotate the `ChoiceBox` in the controller?

Comment: Uh, Thank you, I forgot to annotate "FXML", once again thank you.